# How to define 'final' member functions for a class

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make my member functions `final` as in Java, so that the derived classes can not override them?

Comment: Interesting question to ask in an interview... since the answer is to do nothing. (I believe.)

Comment: No Special funtions in c++ avoid in override,just declare virtual and override.

Comment: Question's not very clear.  That you bothered to ask it implied to my mind that you were talking about virtual functions, in which case the answer is no: a class deriving from any class with a virtual function specified in an ancestor can override the function.  As others have pointed out, sans "virtual", all functions can't be overridden.  I don't know Java, so I'm not sure what it allows when....

Comment: Yes and it is usefull for optimization as the compiler knows that it does not need to call the method via the VMT but directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is so much possible that it is in fact the default behaviour. I.e. if you don't declare your class instance methods explicitly as `virtual`, they can't be [overridden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) in subclasses (only [hidden](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9), which is a different - and almost always erroneous - case).

Effective C++ Third Edition, Item 36 deals with this in detail. Consider

```
class B {
public:
  virtual void vf();
  void mf();
  virtual void mf(int);
  ...
};

class D: public B {
public:
  virtual void vf();              // overrides B::vf
  void mf();                      // hides B::mf; see Item33
  ...
};

D x;                              // x is an object of type D
B *pB = &x;                       // get pointer to x
D *pD = &x;                       // get pointer to x

pD->vf();                         // calls D::mf, as expected
pB->vf();                         // calls D::mf, as expected
pD->mf();                         // calls D::mf, as expected
pB->mf();                         // calls B::mf - surprise!
pD->mf(1);                        // error -  D::mf() hides B::mf(int)!
pB->mf(1);                        // calls B::mf(int)
```

So this is not exactly how `final` behaves in Java, but you can only get this close with C++. An alternative might be to prevent subclassing altogether. The technical - working, but not nice - solution to this is to declare all your constructors `private` (and provide a static factory method if you want to allow instantiation of your class, of course).

Comment: if i didn't misunderstood, then 'Overriding' is to hide the base class' copy, which is very much possible in this case.

What I want is to force the derived classes to always use/call the base class' copy of function.

Comment: I don't know Java, but from what I heard I thought in Java you were unable to even declare `D::mf()`.

Comment: @sbi, yes, that's correct. Trying to override a `final` method in Java results in a compiler error. So the default C++ behaviour is not equivalent to that of `final` in Java, although AFAIK many C++ compilers issue a warning about method hiding.

Comment: I think ... I almost got the rationale. +1 for referring 'Effective C++', it clears the doubts.

Comment: There's another trick to prevent inheritance, which is to add a virtual base class which (a) has a private constructor, and (b) declares your class a `friend`. Constructors of virtual bases must be accessible to the most-derived class, so any derived class of your class can't be instantiated (although it can be defined). But, your class can be instantiated, so unlike your version you don't end up with a heap-only class. Can be done as a CRTP template. Downside: might make the objects bigger.

Comment: The link [hidden](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) is not accessible.

Answer (score 24):

C++11 adds a `final` contextual keyword to support this:

```
class B
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() final;
};
class D : B
{
  public:
    virtual void foo(); // error: declaration of 'foo' overrides a 'final' function
};
```

`final` is supported in GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.0.  And as Sergius notes in his answer, MSVC++ supports it (with the spelling `sealed`), since MSVC++2005.  So if you encapsulate in a mini-macro and set it depending on your compiler, you can be on your way with this.  Just make sure you actually *are* using such a compiler at least every so often, so you'll detect any mistakes early.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation) from Bjarne (Can I stop people deriving from my class?)

Comment: A [direct](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation) link could have been more useful :p.

Comment: @sbi: Oh, yeah, edit rights. I have those now. I forgot. >_<.

Comment: but i ask about preventing the member function, not the whole class from being sub-classed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible if you are using MSVC. There is a `sealed` keyword. Here is an [example from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8ew2153.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

New C++11 standard now supports explicit overrides and final of member functions!